# Couldn't be parked: Ngaio Marsh

Tags: phrases, idioms, british-english

In one of her novels, Dame Ngaio Marsh has Roderick Alleyn propose marriage to Agatha Troy, who responds she "couldn't be parked."  In context this appears to be equivalent to "couldn't be more certain" that she does love him,  but I can't see how you get from the latter to the former.

Comment: Could you quote the entire paragraph for us? I'm not sure from your description how much _parked_ is supposed to mean here, but it doesn't sound like a usage I've come across before.

Comment: My guess is it's a pun, a running gag based on language or events that occurred earlier in the narrative.

Comment: In fact, with just that snippet of a phrase in the context given, the meaning I would take is "I can't be tied down", "I'm not ready for marriage" or "I'm not the marrying sort".

Comment: _lobe him_? Should that be _love him_?

Comment: @Dan-Bron Incidentally, the word 'parked' appears five times in the text, including the time referred to in the question. None of the other usages are figurative.

Comment: When/where is the book set?

Answer (score 3):

The entire text of the book is available online [at this page](http://ebooks.rahnuma.org/krizma/1-Uncatagorized/Death%20in%20a%20White%20Tie.pdf).

However, the question arises from the last lines of the final chapter:

> "Do you think he really knows Davidson did the murder?"
>
> "I think we shall find that Davidson tried to warn him against collecting Evelyn Carrados's bag at the ball. Davidson saw Bunchy was with Evelyn, when Bridget returned her bag the first time."
>
> "You didn't tell me about that."
>
> Alleyn told her about it.
>
> "And isn't that really all?" he asked.
>
> "Yes. That's all."
>
> "Troy, I love you more than anything in life. I've tried humility; God knows, I am humble. And I've tried effrontery. If you can't love me, tell me so, and please let us not meet again because I can't manage meeting you unless it is to love you."
>
> Troy raised a white face and looked solemnly at him.
>
> "I know my mind at last," she said. "I couldn't be parked."
>
> "Darling, darling Troy."
>
> "I do love you. Very much indeed."
>
> "Wonder of the world!" cried Alleyn, and took her in his arms.

It's pretty clear from this exchange that Troy is turning down Alleyn's proposal, despite her professed love for him.  Though Allen has been in turn "humble" and rather less so (his "effrontery") she can only "solemnly" look with her pallid face after he lays his feelings out quite plainly.  Also, by looking back from the final lines a bit further over the entire conversation, Troy's mood is stylistically evoked by her terse answers and brief questions that contrast to Alleyn's rather garrulous paragraphs.

Though the phrase "I couldn't be parked" might seem a bit murky - and perhaps Marsh intended it to be interpretable - in context it refers to her not wanting to settle down.  Idiomatically, she can't be "parked" in one space for the rest of her life.

(N.B.  There are, universally, only seven google search returns for "I couldn't be parked" - and all the others besides this refer to the experience of actually parking in a car.)

Comment: Honestly, if those are the last lines in the book, I don’t find it clear at all from the exchange that Troy is turning down the proposal. The rest of the exchange would fit just as well (actually, _better_) with Troy accepting the proposal. I agree that ‘tied down’ is probably the most likely interpretation, but it is a most abstruse wording to plump down into a most ambiguous context.

Comment: My first thought on reading the question was, like others, "I am not willing to make a commitment." But from the following lines, she seems to be accepting his proposal. I mean, someone might turn down a proposal and then say, "I do love you", in the sense of "but not that way" or "but other considerations prevent me from being willing to marry you". But if that was the intent, why would she go along with him "taking her in his arms". Perhaps the intended meaning was "I wasn't able to make a decision before now."

Comment: @Jay: I think you're right. When she says *"I couldn't be parked"* and not *"I can't be parked"*, maybe she's explaining why she turned down his proposal earlier. Anyway, the first mention of Troy in the following book appears to be in a letter Alleyn writes to her, and they are apparently engaged.

Comment: I don’t know what it means, perhaps it refers to an earlier conversation in the book. But those who have suggested it means she is turning him down are mistaken, because he’d hardly be embracing her if that was the case, and in the next book they are married.

Comment: It is important not to forget that, although *could* has many other uses, sometimes it functions simply as a past tense of *can*.

Comment: Has she come around to parking herself, since she was not one to be parked?

Answer (score 2):

Having read *Artists in Crime* and *Death in a White Tie* and the passage in question several times, I think “***I couldn’t be parked***” means the same as ***“I couldn’t be STAYED,”*** as in,

> I could not be stayed from loving you, despite my fright.

It fits the context best.

Answer (score 1):

In the supplied quote, Alleyn makes no proposal of marriage. He confesses his love and asks Troy if she loves him. So all this talk about marriage seems hasty.

The compact OED says one definition of "park" is to put something aside in a convenient place, to be reclaimed when needed, as in "Park your valise in the corner." It's been a while since I read this book, so I don't recall if the effrontery Alleyn alludes to was his exclusion of Troy from his activities, in effect parking her, thus angering her and causing her to behave in a way that suggested to Alleyn that she could not love him. If so, her saying "I couldn't be parked" could be her explanation to him of that behavior. I.e., "If it seemed I couldn't love you, that is why."

Answer (score 0):

His effrontery was in daring to say, "I am your man."  I agree with the last comment that she couldn't be stayed. He has suggested they not meet again if Troy doesn't love him and she replies in effect that she won't be left like a parked car but she will see him again. Cars were relatively new at the time and the idea of parking a car and coming back or perhaps not coming back to it would have been a novel expression. You can't park a horse.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: What do you mean by **stayed**? Held back from doing something?